# Ruby on rails: devise :, how can i allow posts/index and posts/show action to all but other actions will be denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Howw can i allow posts/index and posts/show action to all but other actions will be denied ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your PostsController

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `except' for PostsController:Class

Comment: should be `:except` instead of `except`